# How to change css in php file

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using post navigation for my blog. For this portion i wrote some css. It's working fine. But the problem is for the very latest post , it's showing blank space for next post link. Same thing is happened with oldest post, it's showing again bank space for previous post link. [image]

I add code snippet for this portion. Can i anyone suggest how can i modify my css for this portion. Following code is embedded in php file.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="sewl-more-posts">
        <div class="previous-post">
            <?php If(previous_post_link()){?>
            <span class="post-control-link">Previous Article</span>
            <span class="post-name"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></span>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="next-post">
            <?php If(next_post_link()){?>
            <span class="post-control-link">Next Article</span>
            <span class="post-name"><?php next_post_link(); ?></span>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the code to reproduce your problem. Php won't work in snippets too.

Comment: i am using wordpress. this code is main code for generating post navigation. Apart from this i have some css for styling. i want to change some style if previous_post is not exist. like text- align:center.

Comment: why dont you put the if condition before the previous post div tag. so that is there is no previous it wont create it to take up the space. would that be enough to solve your issue. Or do you actually want to be able to style it. It seems to me you want next post to be in the middle if previous post doesnt exist.

Comment: i did it and applied && operation , if both true it shows the previous and next both. but it's showing only one link than for all the pages...i tried lot of things but nothing worked.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, output the divs only if they'll have content:

```
        <div class="sewl-more-posts">
            <?php if (previous_post_link()){?>
                <div class="previous-post">
                <span class="post-control-link">Previous Article</span>
                <span class="post-name"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if (next_post_link()){?>
                <div class="next-post">
                <span class="post-control-link">Next Article</span>
                <span class="post-name"><?php next_post_link(); ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
         </div>
```

This way, if the previous-post or next-post div is missing, you'll be able to target the remaining one with the [`:only-child` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child):

```
.sewl-more-posts > div:only-child {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this with php once the page is generated client-side, therefore you have to use javascript (for example):

```javascript
onclick = documet.getElementById('the id you have').style.property = "blue";
```

Comment: first this code is looking for previous code if its exit, it is showing the title, if not, it's not showing anything. it's fine. i just want to change css . and this css class will depend on the output of previous_post_link i.e. if not exist modify the css class... this is the complete scenario.